# How to parse Ethernet Header of pcap file using Python?

Tags: python

I would like to decode the link-layer type and version of packets in a pcap file using Python. So, I have to parse pcap using Python. Here is my code.

```
import dpkt
import socket
import sys

f = open('filename')
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)

for ts, buf in pcap:
  eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
  ip = eth.data
  tcp = ip.data
    print ts, len(buf)
    print eth
    print ip
    print tcp

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The [dpkt](https://code.google.com/p/dpkt/) python library is maybe not the best tools for this task, according to their website dpkt is best used for:

> fast, simple packet creation / parsing, with definitions for the basic TCP/IP protocols.

Use instead scapy which is a

> powerful interactive packet manipulation program for Python.

You can use a script like this

```
from scapy.all import *
packets = rdpcap('tmp.pcap')
for p in packets:
    (p/Ether()).show()
```

Read [Infinite possibilities with Python's Scapy Module](http://bt3gl.github.io/infinite-possibilities-with-pythons-scapy-module.html) for more details.